# Prophet's performance_metrics horizon

Tags: prediction, prophet

I don't understand how performance_metrics works.

Having this output for the cross_validation() method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Beof.png
And this one for the performance_metrics(): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPH4R.png

Why is it that the performance_metrics() doesn't calculate metrics for when the horizon equals 1 day (knowing that cross_validation() also made predictions 1 day ahead, just like in the first row of said output)? I cannot find the answer for this anywhere